# JavaFX 11 Editable ComboBox throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, javafx-11

I have been endeavoring to implement an event listener for an editable `ComboBox` which will add the edited item to the end of the list in an application, but this throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when the edited item is committed. I do not understand why this should be.

Consequently I have created a simplified application as follows and also tried enclosing the code which adds the edited item in a `Platform.runLater()` block but the issue persists.

Can anybody please suggest what may be causing this exception?

Thanks very much.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ComboBoxTest extends Application {
    ComboBox<String> cbItems;
    Label lblResponse;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("ComboBox Demo");
        FlowPane root = new FlowPane(10, 10);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 240, 120);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        lblResponse = new Label();
        ObservableList<String> items =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5");
        cbItems = new ComboBox<String>(items);
        cbItems.setValue("item1");
        cbItems.setEditable(true);
        lblResponse.setText("Selected item is " + cbItems.getValue());

        // Listen for action events on the combo box.
        cbItems.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent ae) {
                lblResponse.setText("Selected item is " + cbItems.getValue());

                //add the modified item to the end of the list
                int i = cbItems.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
                if(!items.get(i).equals(cbItems.getValue())){
                    items.add(cbItems.getValue());
                }
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().addAll(cbItems, lblResponse);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Good first question! You can even improve it by adding the exact error message and stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [the start of] the stack trace...

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 out of bounds for length 5
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at jfxprjct/jfxtests.ComboBoxTest$1.handle(ComboBoxTest.java:52)
```

Now look at line 52 in file `ComboBoxTest.java`.
(Note that it may be a different line number in your stack trace.)
For me, this is line 52

```java
if(!items.get(i).equals(cbItems.getValue())){
```

In other words, the value of `i` is `-1` (minus one). And `i` is assigned a value in the line preceding the `if` statement.

```java
int i = cbItems.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
```

In other words, there is **no** selected index. So you should first check the value of `i` and not assume that it is a valid index value.

However, a better condition (in my opinion) would be

```java
if(!cbItems.getItems().contains(cbItems.getValue())){
```

Then you don't need the selected index at all.

Comment: Thank you. I had erroneously thought that the edited item would retain the same inex as the originally selected item. Your suggested alternative is more elegant and resolves the issue.